# Problems with undersanding the code

Tags: python

i have found this code for the course on edx.com. Can someone tell me why do i have to use the remainder in the for loop? How does it affect the dict?

```
def buildCoder(shift):
    """
    Returns a dict that can apply a Caesar cipher to a letter.
    The cipher is defined by the shift value. Ignores non-letter characters
    like punctuation, numbers and spaces.

    shift: 0 <= int < 26
    returns: dict
    """
    dict={}
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    for l in range(len(upper)):
        dict[upper[l]] = upper[(l+shift)%len(upper)]
    for l in range(len(lower)):
        dict[lower[l]] = lower[(l+shift)%len(lower)]
    return dict
```

Comment: As written in the documentation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code implements a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). Say the shift value is 1 (this is the "key"). 'A' should then become 'B', 'B' should become 'C', and so on. Everything is obvious right until you reach 'Z'. The way the cipher works is that the value should "roll over" -- 'Z' should become 'A' again.

This is essentially what the remainder does. Say you use numbers instead of letters: 'A' is 0, and 'Z' is 25. You want to encipher the number x. First you add x: (x+shift). But now the value might be outside the legal range 0-25. If it's 26, it should really be 0, and if it's 27, it should really be 1, and so on.

As it turns out, this is mathematically equivalent to taking the remainder after a division by 26. 26%26 == 0, 27%26 == 1, and so on. What it expresses is this: it doesn't matter how many times you've passed around the 26-length cycle -- it only matters how far along you are in your *current* cycle.